# Pass URL parameter to link

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

how can I pass a parameter in a URL to a link on the page. So we have this link setup for all visitors from Facebook.

http://www.domain.com/event?source=facebook

We need to pass the source to the end of a link on the page which leads to a booking engine and registers as a conversion so that

http://www.bookingengine.com/tickets/1234/?ticket=567&event=8910

becomes

http://www.bookingengine.com/tickets/1234/?ticket=567&event=8910&source=facebook

Comment: If you need client side only, this post may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Comment: So you want users to hit a site with the first url example, then turn a link of the second url example into the 3rd example, that right?

Comment: Yes that's correct it's slightly more complicated in that I'm using advanced custom fields for Wordrpess so the line I need to add it to is `echo '<a href="' . get_field('engine_link') . '" class="singleseat">BUY TICKETS</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php echo get_permalink($post_ID)."&source=".$yoursource`;?> as your link, or something to that effect.